# Add values of php variables

Tags: php

my php is pretty basic, also this is currently sandbox code which is why it is SO crude!
Basically, I have a loop that gets product details - Sku, Name and Tax Percentage.
After getting the tax value I have an if else to check if the Tax is equal to 20.
If it is, it outputs the product price ($vatprice). This works to this point.
What I want to do is add all the prices together and output outside the loop. So essentially add each occurrence of $vatprice together and output the total sum.
I'm not sure I'm going about this the right way?

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
   echo '<strong>Sku:</strong> ' . $item->getSku() . '<br/>';
   echo '<strong>Name:</strong> ' . $item->getName() . '<br/>';
   $taxpercent = $item->getData('tax_percent');
   echo '<strong>VAT Percentage:</strong> ' . $taxpercent . '<br/>';
                        
   if ($taxpercent == 20) {
      $vatprice = $item->getPrice();
      echo $vatprice;
      echo '<br/><br/>';
   } else {
      echo '<strong>0%</strong>';
      echo '<br/><br/>';
   }
}
```

Comment: OK, show us what you've tried so far. Basically, create a variable before your loop opens and initialise it to zero, then add the appropriate value to it on each iteration of the loop. After the loop closes, display the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable at first. Then while in the loop, sum the prices and show them at the end of the loop.

```
<?php

$total;
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    echo '<strong>Sku:</strong> ' . $item->getSku() . '<br/>';
    echo '<strong>Name:</strong> ' . $item->getName() . '<br/>';
    $taxpercent = $item->getData('tax_percent');
    echo '<strong>VAT Percentage:</strong> ' . $taxpercent . '<br/>';

    if ($taxpercent == 20) {
        $vatprice = $item->getPrice();
        $total += $vatprice;
        echo $vatprice;
        echo '<br/><br/>';
    } else {
        echo '<strong>0%</strong>';
        echo '<br/><br/>';
    }
}
echo $total;
```